# TFS: weird entries in "Assigned To" list

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

Any idea how I can get rid of those weird entries?

- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.AccountAdmin
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Apps
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.CLT
- [...]

Does not seems to be a local problem as I have the same issue on 2 computers. Also, the problem is present in all of my TFS projects.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: I get the same thing when I use VS2015 against VSTS - This is the first time I've noticed it though, because I have always used the web access for VSTS - even at work on TFS2012, I use Web Access nearly all the time.

Comment: I can get the same behavior as you and submit a feedback on MS Connect Page, please refer to this link for details: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2925575/unexpected-entries-appear-in-assigned-to-list-in-team-explorer-when-connecting-to-a-vsts-team-project

Answer (score 0):

This is as designed for VSTS if you are connecting from VS.  The reason you don't see the identities from Web Access when searching is because the data source is different.  It's connecting to our identity service which can filter down results to only the identities which are users.  You can still manually type in one of those identities above and the work item will save fine.

The VS client uses can only use local metadata, which means it doesn't have the extra information that the identity service has for determining if it should show a user or not in the picker.

I'm sorry for the confusion, and hope this feedback is helpful.